# how to use reflection on Activity.onAttachedToWindow()

Tags: android, reflection, android-activity

I want my app to be able to be run on pre Android 2.0 operating systems (namely 1.5 and 1.6).  I need to include Activity.onAttachedToWindow() for 2.0 and above.  How can I use reflection (or any other approach) to make my app work property on pre-2.0 Android operating systems?

Comment: What do you mean under "include"? Do you want to call this method or override it?

Comment: On another note, I would recommend to think twice before investing your time into 1.5/1.6 support. It's only around 5% of active users, but your code becomes significantly more harder to support. As another option, you could stick with 1.6, and leave 1.5 alone (~2.3% of users).

Comment: I mean I need to override it.  It's kind of a weird case because I'm not the one calling that, so i'm not sure how reflection could play a role here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity`'s `onAttachedToWindow` is empty. This means you can avoid calling `super.onAttachedToWindow`. So the easiest way would be:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{   
     Log.e("TEST", "onAttachedToWindow");               
}
```

Android OS will call your `onAttachedToWindow` on Api Level 5+ (2.0+). And on 1.5/1.6 this function is just never called.

---

If you want to call implementation of `onAttachedToWindow` from super class via reflection:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{   
    Log.e("TEST", "onAttachedToWindow");

    /* calling:
     * super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
     */
    Class<?> activityClass = (Class<?>)getClass().getSuperclass();
    try
    {
        Method superOnAttachedToWindow = activityClass.getMethod("onAttachedToWindow");
        superOnAttachedToWindow.invoke(this);
    }
    catch(InvocationTargetException ex)
    {
        //TODO: add exception handling
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
        //TODO: add exception handling;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException ex)
    {
        //TODO: add exception handling
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodException ex)
    {
        /* you are here if `onAttachedToWindow` does not exist */           
    }

}
```

Comment: should that be: superOnAttachedToWindow.invoke( activityClass );
otherwise i get a stack overflow...

Comment: @user645402 I think changing it to `activityClass`, which means passing a `Class` as `this` to `onAttachedToWindow`, doesn't really help and you probably got an `IllegalArgumentException` which you didn't log.

Comment: @inazaruk I think he's right though, reflection doesn't help here since the documentation for `invoke` says: "*Reflective method invocation follows the usual process for method lookup.*" which means it's polymorphic, hence calling your override, not `super`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5411434/253468; BUT you can use reflection to check whether there's a `super.onAttachedToWindow()` and call it the normal way if no `NoSuchMethodException` was thrown.