# can not access a member of class org.springframework.aop.TruePointcut with modifiers public

Tags: java, spring, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am developing a Spring application using Struts and the Struts JSON plugin. When I run the application it gives the following error (in Firebug):

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.springframework.aop.TruePointcut with modifiers public
```

This is full stack trace:

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class
org.springframework.aop.TruePointcut with modifiers &quot;public&quot;
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:238)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:171)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:127)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:95)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:116)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:196)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:170)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
```

Root cause:

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class
org.springframework.aop.TruePointcut with modifiers &quot;public&quot;
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:238)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:171)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:127)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:363)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:223)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:171)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:127)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:95)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:116)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:196)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:170)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:374)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:278)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249
```

Answer (score 60):

This class is not public itself. It is package protected (see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.5.1/org/springframework/aop/TruePointcut.java)). You have to call `setAccessible(true)` before access its member exactly as when you access private or protected member.

EDIT.
Unfortunately you have not provided full stack trace. If this exception is result of your activity (I mean you try to access member of Spring class yourself) the solution is above. If however this happened as result of frameworks collision please send more details. Probably your versions of Struts and Spring are not compatible or some additional configuration is required.

Comment: I have added full stack trace

Comment: how i can setAccesible(true) and where i should do?

Comment: I found answer.I have added this in to my struts.xml file  <result type="json"> 
  <param name="excludeProperties"> 
   <param name="excludeProperties">patientService</param>
  </param> 
 </result>

Comment: what is patientService means ? @AlexR where can i do setAccesible(true)

Comment: @ChamlyIdunil, read again the answer and the comments. The original question did not include stacktrace, so I did not know whether OP performs reflection call himself or it is done by one of the third party libraries. The later comment of OP shows that the problem is happened because some configuration was missing and OP posted this configuration that included reference to `patientService`. I have no idea what is this but believe that it is the OP's business logic service.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to access public constructor of a non public class.

```
class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {}
}

//...
MyClass c = JsonIterator.deserialize(bytes, MyClass.class)
```

Throws:
`ReflectionMapDecoder can not access a member of class MyClass with modifiers "public"`

Added `public` and it works.

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {}
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

For me that message meant I was calling
`instance.getClass().getMethod("methodName")` 
but for some reason because it was actually defined in a parent class (@Override) this worked instead:
`instance.getClass().getSuperClass().getMethod("methodName")`

ref: [How to call a superclass method using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411434/how-to-call-a-superclass-method-using-java-reflection)