# Call overridden method of super class

Tags: java

This question was asked to me in an interview. I have an overridden method in my sub-class. Using an instance of the subclass, I want to call the method of the super class. Bear in mind that the method is overridden.

The output of the following code is `NO NO PRINT HI`.
What if I want to print `Print Hello` using the object of overriding class? How do I do that?

```
class OverrideSuper {
    public void printHello() {
         System.out.println("Print Hello");
    }
}

public class Overriding extends OverrideSuper {
    public void printHello() {
         System.out.println("NO NO PRINT HI");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //OverrideSuper obj1 = new OverrideSuper();
        Overriding obj2 = new Overriding();
        obj2.printHello();// this calls printHello() of class Overriding.
        //I want to call printHello() of OverrideSuper using obj2. How do I do that???
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any research? How do you typically call a parent class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will fulfil your requirement!! try this
when you call `obj2.printHello();` execution will move to `Overriding`s `printHello()` and in that method i ve used `super.printHello();` this means first invoke super class's `printHello()` `and compiler prints Print Hello` then execution again come to `Overriding`s `printHello()` and `print NO NO PRINT HI`

```
class OverrideSuper {
    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Print Hello");
    }
}
    public class Overriding extends OverrideSuper {
            public void printHello() {
                super.printHello();
                System.out.println("NO NO PRINT HI");
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // OverrideSuper obj1 = new OverrideSuper();
                Overriding obj2 = new Overriding();
                obj2.printHello();// this calls printHello() of class Overriding.
                // I want to call printHello() of OverrideSuper using obj2. How do I do
                // that???
            }
        }
```

**output**

```
Print Hello
NO NO PRINT HI
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the interviewer expected you to write another method that calls `super.printHello()`:

```
public class Overriding extends OverrideSuper {
    public void printHello(){
         System.out.println("NO NO PRINT HI");
    }
    public void superHello() { // You can make this private or protected, too
        super.printHello();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //OverrideSuper obj1 = new OverrideSuper();
        Overriding obj2 = new Overriding();
        obj2.superHello();// this calls printHello() of class OverrideSuper .
    }
}
```

Essentially, he wanted you to tell him that once a method is overriden, there is no way to call through to the method of the base class from the outside. The only way around it is to make a calling path into the superclass on the inside of the overriding class, which is what I did above by defining a `superHello` method.

> [The interviewer] said "I am not convinced"

Another possibility could be that the interviewer was looking for you to provide a reflection-based solution, which is possible only in Java 7+. You need to use `MethodHandle`, call `findSpecial` with the base class, and then invoke the method that you get back.

[Here is a link to an answer that explains the process, and shows an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674467/335858)

Comment: Excatly, this is what I actually did answer. However, the interviewer was constantly irritating me by saying " No No I want to call from obj2."
When I said its not possible. He said " I am not convinced"...
Any case I know that I was correct. Thanks a lot people :) Have a good day.... :)