# How to call an overriden method using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

Consider we have the following:

```
 class Base { def name = "Base" }
 class Successor extends Base {
    override def name = "Successor"
 }
```

I have tried to do the following (took from [How to call a superclass method using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411434/how-to-call-a-superclass-method-using-java-reflection)):

```
import java.lang.invoke.{MethodHandles, MethodHandle, MethodType}

object TestApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val a = new Successor;
        val h1 = MethodHandles.lookup().findSpecial(classOf[Base],
                                                    "name",
                                                    MethodType.methodType(classOf[String]),
                                                    classOf[Successor]);
        println(h1.invoke(a));
    }
}
```

but I get a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no private access for invokespecial: class Successor, from TestApp$
```

I was told that it is possible that Java reflection may not work correctly for Scala. Is it true? Or I simply do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is possible and Java reflection works for Scala as well, I just didn't read all answers for [How to call a superclass method using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411434/how-to-call-a-superclass-method-using-java-reflection).

The following code works:

```
object TestApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val a = new Successor;
        val impl_lookup = classOf[MethodHandles.Lookup].getDeclaredField("IMPL_LOOKUP")
        impl_lookup.setAccessible(true)
        val lkp = impl_lookup.get(null).asInstanceOf[MethodHandles.Lookup];
        val h1 = lkp.findSpecial(classOf[Base],
                                "name",
                                MethodType.methodType(classOf[String]),
                                classOf[Successor])
        println(h1.invoke(a)) // prints "Base"
        println(a.name)       // prints "Successor"
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Jesse Glick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12916/jesse-glick) for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can NOT even do it in Java. Note, in the answer of "How to call a superclass method using Java reflection", it works because the Test extends the Base: `public class Test extends Base {...}`.