# How to call a BaseClass method through an extended instance

Tags: java, inheritance

Please consider the following classes:

```
public interface BaseInterface {

    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
}


public class BaseClass implements BaseInterface {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method1 IN");
        this.method3();
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method1 OUT");
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method2 IN");
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method2 OUT");
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method3 IN");
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method3 OUT");
    }
}


public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method1 IN");
        super.method1();
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method1 OUT");
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method2 IN");
        super.method2();
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method2 OUT");
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method3 IN");
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method3()");
        System.out.println("ChildClass.method3 OUT");
    }
}
```

In this case, if I create an instance of `ChildClass`:

```
BaseInterface cc1 = new ChildClass();
```

and then run `method1` of this class

```
cc1.method1();
```

it will return the following output:

```
ChildClass.method1 IN
BaseClass.method1 IN
ChildClass.method3 IN
ChildClass.method3()
ChildClass.method3 OUT
BaseClass.method1 OUT
ChildClass.method1 OUT
```

So when I call `this.method3()` (or just `method3()`) from the super class (`BaseClass`), the `method3` of the `ChildClass` is executed instead. I know this is the expected behavior but I just wonder how can I still call the `BaseClass.method3` in this setup? Is this possible?

Please note that this is a purely theoretical question and I understand that in reality I probably should've instantiated a `BaseClass` instance in the first place. Is this the only way to get around that?

Comment: Here's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674467/32090

Comment: @BorisPavlović Thanks, that's an interesting solution.

Comment: i think its late to comment but when i ran above program  my o/p is differnt from yours..                                                      
`code`                                                                              ChildClass.method1 IN
BaseClass.method1 IN
BaseClass.method3 IN
BaseClass.method3 OUT
BaseClass.method1 OUT
ChildClass.method1 OUT . `code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around would be to create a private method in `BaseClass` and call that from `method3` like this:

```
public class BaseClass implements BaseInterface {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method1 IN");
        this.internalMethod3();
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method1 OUT");
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method2 IN");
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method2 OUT");
    }
    private void internalMethod3() {

        System.out.println("BaseClass.method3 IN");
        System.out.println("BaseClass.method3 OUT");
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        this.internalMethod3();
    }
}
```

Would accomplish the same thing

Also a comment about the solution posted in [How to call a superclass method using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411434/how-to-call-a-superclass-method-using-java-reflection/15674467#15674467) is that you should not do it this way if possible. Refactoring your code break it down to smaller functions would be the way to go here. As this question formulated there is no problem in refactoring the code.

Comment: you have changed the problem statement itself. This was intention to have the contract and then implement.

Comment: @spandey15 Not sure what you're saying and I don't see how this answer is different from what davidxxx posted. This fullfills the contract and is how I would do it if the need arises.

Comment: @spandey15 In Java, you don't have other solution because of overriding feature. I explain it in my answer. So you have to use a trick.

Comment: you too @davidxxx :)

Comment: @spandey15 Sorry, didnt see your edit when I updated the  answer. Feel free to apply the edit again

Answer (score 2):

It is the way which overridable methods work : at runtime, the method of the runtime object is invoked.
And here `this.method3();`, `this` is the runtime object and `method3()` an overridable method. So polymorphism takes place.

To achieve the expected behavior, you should so play with access modifiers by using the single one that doesn't allow overriding : `private`.
Delegate the `method3()` implementation into a `private` method and now you can access it from the `method1()` :

```
@Override
public void method1() {
    System.out.println("BaseClass.method1 IN");
    method3Internal();
    System.out.println("BaseClass.method1 OUT");
}

@Override
public void method3() {
    method3Internal();
}

private void method3Internal() {
    System.out.println("BaseClass.method3 IN");
    System.out.println("BaseClass.method3 OUT");
}
```